# NullPointerException when adding ListView from another xml layout

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception, illegalstateexception

```
feedLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
feedLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
//LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_feeds, feedLayout, false);
lstFeeds = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listfeeds);
lstFeeds.setAdapter(new FeedsAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista));
feedLayout.addView(lstFeeds);
```

**Logcat :**

```
IllegalStateException:
The specified child already has a parent you must call removeChild() ...
```

Comment: the logcat already tells you what you must do :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
feedLayout.removeAllViews();
```

before

```
feedLayout.addView(v);
```

EDIT :

```
feedLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
feedLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
//LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_feeds, feedLayout, false);
lstFeeds = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listfeeds);
lstFeeds.setAdapter(new FeedsAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista));
feedLayout.addView(v);
```

Comment: How is this the issue here? `feedLayout = new LinearLayout(this);` creates an empty `LinearLayout`. Why would calling `feedLayout.removeAllViews()` be required?

Comment: @vikram Need to remove views first from parent view.

Comment: Hardy, thanx this solved the problem, sorry about removing my previous comment

Comment: @SomePenguin Its ok.. Happy codding... Glad to help you.

Comment: I see. You had `feedLayout.addView(lstFeeds);` before you edited your answer, in which case, removing views wouldn't have helped. The exception would have been the same. And even now, @SomePenguin can remove `feedLayout.removeAllViews();` from  his/her code without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The better way of doing is making customized adapter extenting base adapter and inflating the layout in getView() method.